# UITableView last row is getting cut off

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My UITable's last row is getting cut off. 
[image]

Code

```
@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedFood: foodItem = foodItem()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set delegates and initialize foodModel
        self.listTableView.delegate = self
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self

        self.listTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 115
        //self.listTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        let FoodModel = foodModel()
        FoodModel.delegate = self
        FoodModel.downloadItems()

    }
```

When I tried to add the line, self.listTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. It gives me something strange
[image]

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the solutions was fitting for my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked to see if the bottom of the table view is off the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I just checked, and it isn't

Comment: Have you used `autoLayout` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I set the constraints to the suggested constraints

Comment: There in lies your problem probably! Have a look at the constraints and figure out what needs to be added/removed to make `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions` work. That being said, when you said `UITableView` is cut-off, it should be the bottom of the screen and the `UITableView` should be scrollable.

Comment: So, yeah, i managed to fix the issue with UITableViewAutomaticDimension issue and it is displaying my cells as it should, but the end is still getting cut off. I think my issue is I am not sure what auto-layout fixing I should do. And yes, the UITableView is scrollable.

Comment: Is your `UITableView` properly constrained with a leading, top, bottom and trailing to its `superView`? If not, ensure it has 0 spacing or atleast positive constraint value with its superview on all sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set proper layout constraints from your labels to all edges of the cell.

If all of the labels can have fixed height of one row, you can set a height constraint also.

If any of the labels can have multiple rows you'll have to set priority, content hugging etc.

Look it up: https://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/auto-layout-intro.html

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I am having issue understanding how the auto-layout should be done to result in correct rendering.

Comment: I think its best if you check out this video, auto layout is very well explained. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH_Ye-8ii8E

Answer (score 0):

When using auto-layout and the Navigation Controller, be sure that the constraint for Table View.bottom is equal to Bottom Layout Guide.top, and not with the View.  That was my problem.